# restricting sed command

Tags: sed

I have a variables that needs to be modified so that minutes %M is added. I know the sed command and it is working as expected.

```
# cat mysed.txt 
myfirstfile="comany$mydb`date +'%d-%b-%Y-%H'`.sql"

# sed -i 's/\%H/\%H-\%M/' mysed.txt
# cat mysed.txt 
myfirstfile="company$mydb`date +'%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M'`.sql"
```

But if I run the same sed command again, it will add %M again as follows.

```
# sed -i 's/\%H/\%H-\%M/' mysed.txt

# cat mysed.txt 
myfirstfile="company$mydb`date +'%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M-%M'`.sql"
```

I need a sed command that should add the minutes %M only once even if sed command is executed twice (by mistake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# sed -i "s/%H'/%H-%M'/" mysed.txt
```

This should work. This way it will only do the replacement if there is a quote mark next to the %H.

Comment: You have the right idea, but some of your syntax is off -- both shell syntax (you can't embed `'` inside `'...'` by using `\'`, because the backslash isn't recognized as special inside `'...'`) and `sed` syntax (you need an `/` at the end). Also, there's no reason to put a backslash in front of `%`. (The OP did it, but it's not needed.) So, I think you want to write `"s/%H'/%H-%M'/"`.

Answer (score 0):

Test if it is present before substituting:

```
sed '/%H-%M/! s/%H/%H-%M/' mysed.txt
```

Btw. `%` does not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I believe below command will work fine.Please replace test.dat file with your file name.

```
cat test.dat|sed "s/\%H\'/\%H\-\%M\'/" > test.dat
```

Without cat command

```
sed -i "s/\%H\'/\%H\-\%M\'/" test.dat >  test.dat
```

Cheers!